# Micronaut @EachProperty converts camel case variable names to kebab case from configuration file

Tags: java, micronaut

I'm facing an issue with Micronaut's @EachProperty annotation. It seems that when using @EachProperty to map configuration properties, the variable names in the annotated class are being converted to kebab case, even if they are originally in camel case in the configuration file.

This behavior is causing inconsistencies and making it difficult to maintain a consistent naming convention between the configuration file and the annotated class. Ideally, I would expect the variable names to be preserved in their original format as they appear in the configuration file.

Has anyone else encountered this issue with Micronaut's @EachProperty? Is there a known solution or workaround to preserve the raw format of variable names from the configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

According to Micronaut documentation [https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#propertySource]](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#propertySource%5D), at `Property Value Binding`:

> Note that these property references should be in kebab case (lowercase and
> hyphen-separated) when placing references in code or in placeholder
> values. For example, use micronaut.server.default-charset and not
> micronaut.server.defaultCharset.
>
> The Micronaut framework still allows specifying the latter in
> configuration, but normalizes the properties into kebab case form to
> optimize memory consumption and reduce complexity when resolving properties.

Micronaut is picky about configuration properties and there's not much you can do about it.

The preferred way is to use kebab case in your Micronaut configuration file.